# How to build nested properties from key strings

Tags: javascript, object, nested

```
var keys1 = ["foo", "moreFoo"],
value1 = "bar",
keys2 = ["foo", "ultraFoo"],
value2 = "bigBar";
```

I'd like to make a function which would build me an object :

```
object {
foo : {moreFoo: "bar", ultraFoo: "bigBar"}
}
```

I thought of taking each one of my arrays and doing the following :

```
function recursiveObjectBuild(object, keys, value) {
    var index = 0;
    function loop(object, index) {
        var key = keys[index];
        //Property exists, go into it
        if (key in object) {
            loop(object[key], ++index);
        //Property doesn't exist, create it and go into it
        } else if (index < keys.length-1) {
            object[key] = {};
            loop(object[key], ++index);
        //At last key, set value
        } else {
            object[key] = value;
            return object;
        }
    }
    return loop(object, 0);
}
```

Which should work IMO but doesn't (infinite loop, must be a stupid mistake but can't see it).

And I'm sure there must be a much simpler way

Comment: Please explain with pseudo-code, it would be better :)

Comment: Seems line#6 is an issue. i don't see where "object" gets set:  " if (key in object) {". Also, why  not use JSON in your object builder?

Comment: @mohamed-abshir object is received as a parameter by the recursive function
How would you do it with JSON ?

Comment: @flav the array of keys is a nested set of keys. [foo, bar, foobar] means that i want to set the properties to Object.foo.bar.foobar
Also, all those properties will be defined in the same object

Comment: Here is the Json syntax for the sample above: var JSONObject= {
 "foo":"bar",
 "moreFoo":"bigBar",
 "Altrafoo":bigBar
  };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function objectBuild(object, keys, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length-1; i++) {
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(keys[i]))
            object[keys[i]] = {};
        object = object[keys[i]];
    }
    object[keys[keys.length-1]] = value;
}
```

Example usage ([see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/7SU2H/)):

```
var object = {};
objectBuild(object, ["foo", "moreFoo"], "bar");
objectBuild(object, ["foo", "ultraFoo"], "bigBar");
// object --> {foo: {moreFoo: "bar", ultraFoo: "bigBar}}
```